# Regex to Remove HTML Tags

Tags: regex

input:

```
<td>
<span>
<span>spanaaa</span>
<span class="1">spanbbb</span>
<span class="" style="">spanccc</span>
<span style="display:none">spanddd</span>

<div>divaaa</div>
<div class="1">divbbb</div>
<div class="" style="">divccc</div>
<div style="display:none">divddd</div>
</span>
</td>
```

I need a regular express or a method in order to get the values without attribute style="display:none"

output:

> spanaaa
>   spanbbb
>   spanccc
>
> divaaa
>   divbbb
>   divccc

Comment: [Regular expressions are an exceptionally poor tool to use when parsing anything but trivial HTML.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: You want a server side solution or a client side solution?

Comment: How do you want to do this ? One method is to use [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)

Answer (score 1):

**The pattern [.NET flavor]**

```
(?<=<\w+ [^<>]*?\w+=")(?!display:none)(?<mt>[^"<>]+)(?=")

Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks

Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=<\w+ [^<>]*?\w+=")»
   Match the character “<” literally «<»
   Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Match the character “ ” literally « »
   Match a single character NOT present in the list “<>” «[^<>]*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Match the characters “="” literally «="»
Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!display:none)»
   Match the characters “display:none” literally «display:none»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “mt” «(?<mt>[^"<>]+)»
   Match a single character NOT present in the list “"<>” «[^"<>]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=")»
   Match the character “"” literally «"»
```

**The pattern [PCRE]**

```
<!--
(<\w+ [^<>]*?\w+=")(?!display:none)([^"<>]+)(?=")

Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks

Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(<\w+ [^<>]*?\w+=")»
   Match the character “<” literally «<»
   Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Match the character “ ” literally « »
   Match a single character NOT present in the list “<>” «[^<>]*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Match the characters “="” literally «="»
Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!display:none)»
   Match the characters “display:none” literally «display:none»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «([^"<>]+)»
   Match a single character NOT present in the list “"<>” «[^"<>]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=")»
   Match the character “"” literally «"»
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is a poor choice for this (because of the vagaries of HTML), however you may try this:

```
<div(?!\s*style="display:none")[^>]*>(.*?)</div>
```

Comment: Is the `=` in `(?!=` a typo?  Because it's not part of the lookahead itself (that's either `(?=` or `(?!`), but it will never match a literal `=` in that position either.

Comment: @AlanMoore My bad! Thanks for picking that up. I've corrected the regex in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"<div style=""display:none"">(.|\n)*?</div>", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Here input is the string that contains Html. Try this regex, it will work!

Answer (score 0):

It is CSharp version that 8x faster than regex parsing. You can easily convert to any language you would like.

```
public static string StripTagsCharArray(string source)
{
char[] array = new char[source.Length];
int arrayIndex = 0;
bool inside = false;

for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
{
    char let = source[i];
    if (let == '<')
    {
    inside = true;
    continue;
    }
    if (let == '>')
    {
    inside = false;
    continue;
    }
    if (!inside)
    {
    array[arrayIndex] = let;
    arrayIndex++;
    }
}
return new string(array, 0, arrayIndex);
}
```